# How do I check if an ember computed property has a setter defined?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have an Ember.Object *obj*, with a property *propPath*.

I'm trying to implement:

```
function isComputedPropertyWithNoSetter(obj, propPath) {
    // what do I do here?
    // something involving Ember.meta(obj) perhaps?
}
```

So I can do:

```
var hasStaticProp = Ember.Object.extend({ prop: 5 }).create();
isComputedPropertyWithNoSetter(hasStaticProp, 'prop');
// => false

var hasComputedPropertyWithSetter = Ember.Object.extend({ prop: function (k, v, d) { }.property() }).create();
isComputedPropertyWithNoSetter(hasComputedPropertyWithSetter, 'prop');
// => false

var hasComputedPropertyNoSetter = Ember.Object.extend({ prop: function () { }.property() }).create();
isComputedPropertyWithNoSetter(hasComputedPropertyNoSetter, 'prop');
// => true
```

I'm writing 'tree-walking' state serialization code for a large established ember codebase. When I restore state, I want a guard check to make sure I never accidentally overwrite a read-only (getter only) computed property with a static value.

I need to implement this function so I can do....

```
if (!isComputedPropertyWithNoSetter(obj, propPath) {
    // not going to accidentally overwrite a computed property with a static value
    Ember.set(obj, propPath, serializedStaticValue); 
}
```

I realize this is fairly dicey, and the solution might be a not entirely recommended hack.